# Printing a dict in alphabetical order vertically next to a vertical line of letters?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

Okay so my teacher gave us this code to print out the alphabet vertically:

```
for k in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):   
         print(k,chr(k))
```

this prints

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

etc...

and we have a dict of seats assigned seat numbers for the keys like a5,b48,c30 etc

he wants us to print this:

```
a    {a5:example,ex} , {a12:example,ex}
b
c    {c40:example,ex}
d
e
f
```

etc...

I know how to print a dict vertically by using

```
for x,y in myDict.items()
      print(x,':',y)
```

but how do I place them next to the vertical letters?

Comment: where is  `{a12:example,ex} ` etc.. coming from?

Answer (score 0):

By default in Python, as in many languages, you print line by line. So, before using print expression you might want 'build' the entire line you need to print. For example you might want to do something like:

```
space = ' ' * 10
for x,y in myDict.items():
    line = '%s: %s' % (x,y)
    if condition_to_add_extra_elements_in_this_line:
        line += space + whatever_else_you_want_to_add_in_this_line
    print line
```

Where condition_to_add_extra_elements_in_this_line is the condition that determines if you need to add something else in this line and whatever_else_you_want_to_add_in_this_line are the extra stuff you need to add. You should replace these and also you might need to use a for expression instead the if.

Comment: Only problem with this is that I need to have the seat numbers line  up with their corresponding letter ex(a5,c30,t40) and the dictionary is being updated in the program

Comment: Same idea, first make all the calculations then do the print.